# convert dplyr to sql

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr

I have data structured as follows:

```
id  start       end          cancelled
1   2020-01-01  2020-12-31   2021-01-10
1   2021-02-01  2022-01-31   NA
2   2020-01-01  2020-12-31   NA
3   2020-01-01  2020-06-30   2020-07-01
3   2020-07-10  2021-01-09   2021-01-31
3   2021-02-02  2021-08-01   NA
```

These data represent club memberships and the goal is to extract those members who cancel their membership and later re-join. In particular I am interested in the number of days between cancellation and re-joining.

In R I can do:

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3), start = c("2020-01-01", 
"2021-02-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-07-10", "2021-02-02"
), end = c("2020-12-31", "2022-01-31", "2020-12-31", "2020-06-30", 
"2021-01-09", "2021-08-01"), cancelled = c("2021-01-10", NA, 
NA, "2020-07-01", "2021-01-31", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)) %>%

dat[,-1] <- lapply(dat[,-1], as.Date)
dat %>%
group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(
    rejoin_date = start[-1],
    time_to_rejoin = as.numeric(start[-1] - cancelled[-n()], units="days")
  ) %>% drop_na(time_to_rejoin) %>%
  ungroup()
```

where `drop_na(time_to_rejoin)` handles the cases where a member has multiple concurrent uncancelled memberships, which results in:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3

     id rejoin_date time_to_rejoin
      1 2021-02-01              22
      3 2020-07-10               9
      3 2021-02-02               2
```

How can I do this in MySQL ?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dat` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `start` TIMESTAMP,
  `end` TIMESTAMP,
  `cancelled` TIMESTAMP NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `dt` (`id`, `start`, `end`, `cancelled`) VALUES
  ('1', '2020-01-01', '2020-12-31', '2021-01-10'),
  ('2', '2021-02-01', '2022-01-31', NULL ),
  ('2', '2021-01-01', '2020-12-31', NULL ),
  ('3', '2020-01-01', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-01'),
  ('3', '2020-07-10', '2021-01-09', '2021-01-31'),
  ('3', '2021-02-02', '2021-08-01', NULL )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/252e6d6

Comment: Note that, by convention, a column called 'id' is normally a surrogate PRIMARY KEY

Comment: @Strawberry thanks, you're right. I was just trying to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.id, 
       COALESCE(t1.cancelled, t1.end) `end`, 
       t2.start next_start, 
       DATEDIFF(t2.start, COALESCE(t1.cancelled, t1.end)) gap
FROM dat t1
JOIN dat t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
           AND COALESCE(t1.cancelled, t1.end) < t2.start
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM dat t3
                   WHERE t1.id = t3.id
                     AND COALESCE(t1.cancelled, t1.end) < t3.start
                     AND COALESCE(t3.cancelled, t3.end) < t2.start )
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e822fab2c63812c4f815f2700e62dd7e

PS. Errorneous src data (typo?) in the fiddle fixed.

PPS. If you do not need to return adjacent periods then add `HAVING gap > 1` to the most end of the query.

---

> Could you add a description of how it works ? – Joe King

`t1` and `t2` table copies are used for to retrieve "previous" and "next" periods.

`t3` allows to ensure that they are adjacent (there is no any period between the periods taken from `t1` and `t2`).

I.e. if we have 3 periods then JOIN produces 3 pairs (1-2), (2-3), (1-3), but WHERE removes the last pair because there exists period 2 between periods 1 and 3.

COALESCE is used for to take `cancelled` if it is set and `end` is it is not set (is NULL).

Comment: (+) Thank you, this seems to work well. Could you add a description of how it works ?

Comment: @JoeKing Some explanations added.